# Pcap4j packet capture on loopback doesn't differentiate between Incoming and Outgoing packets

Tags: java, networking, pcap4j

I am writing a simple packet capture & processing engine for my project using pacp4j. Below is the code that I am using to capture packets but when I use it to capture ONLY incoming packets on loopback address it gives me both outgoing and incoming packets.

How can I differentiate between incoming and outgoing packets on loopback address?

```
    public class PacketListner {

  int packet_count = 0;
  private static final String READ_TIMEOUT_KEY
      = PacketListner.class.getName() + ".readTimeout";
  private static final int READ_TIMEOUT
      = Integer.getInteger(READ_TIMEOUT_KEY, 10); // [ms]

  private static final String SNAPLEN_KEY
      = PacketListner.class.getName() + ".snaplen";
  private static final int SNAPLEN
      = Integer.getInteger(SNAPLEN_KEY, 65536); // [bytes]

  private static final String TIMESTAMP_PRECISION_NANO_KEY
      = PacketListner.class.getName() + ".timestampPrecision.nano";
  private static final boolean TIMESTAMP_PRECISION_NANO
      = Boolean.getBoolean(TIMESTAMP_PRECISION_NANO_KEY);

  public int sniff() throws PcapNativeException, NotOpenException {

    PcapNetworkInterface nif = null;
    try {
      nif = new NifSelector().selectNetworkInterface();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (nif == null) {
      return -1;
    }

    System.out.println(nif.getName() + "(" + nif.getDescription() + ")");

    PcapHandle.Builder phb
        = new PcapHandle.Builder(nif.getName())
        .snaplen(SNAPLEN)
        .direction(PcapHandle.PcapDirection.IN)
        .promiscuousMode(PcapNetworkInterface.PromiscuousMode.PROMISCUOUS)
        .timeoutMillis(READ_TIMEOUT);

    if (TIMESTAMP_PRECISION_NANO) {
      phb.timestampPrecision(PcapHandle.TimestampPrecision.NANO);
    }

    PcapHandle handle = phb.build();

    while (true) {
      Packet packet = handle.getNextPacket();
      if (packet != null) {
        if (packet.contains(IpV4Packet.class) &&
            (packet.contains(TcpPacket.class) || packet.contains(UdpPacket.class))) {
          IpV4Packet pkt = packet.get(IpV4Packet.class);
          if (packet.contains (TcpPacket.class)) {
             TcpPacket tcpPkt = packet.get(TcpPacket.class);
             System.out.println(pkt.getHeader().getSrcAddr() + ":" + tcpPkt.getHeader().getDstPort());
          }
          else {
             UDpPacket udpPkt = packet.get(UDpPacket.class);
             System.out.println(pkt.getHeader().getSrcAddr() + ":" + udpPkt.getHeader().getDstPort());
          }

        }
       packet_count++;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How wrong? What's your OS?

Comment: @kaitoy I am on Ubuntu 14.04. I figured out that its a problem with loopback address. I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: On loopback interface, outgoing packets are incomming packets, right? I don't understand what you want.